# Border transition анимация рамки на кнопке

Tags: анимация, css-animation, border

Привет ребятам.
Есть такое вот дело [code pen](http://codepen.io/semenchenko/pen/gwjNZv?editors=1100)

```
<div class="btn__submit">
```

Отправить

```
 .btn__submit {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 127px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

[type="submit"] {
    margin: 27px 0 0 0;
    font-family: "futura-demic-reg", sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 1.5px;
    text-transform: lowercase;
    display: block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 9px 0;
    max-width: 127px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #111;
    background: transparent;
    -webkit-transition: all .34s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .34s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .34s ease-in-out;
}

.line__wrap span {
  display: block;
  background: #ffb400;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.line__wrap span:nth-of-type(1){ 
  width: 0%; height: 2px; top: 0; left: 0;  
  animation: lineWidth .25s ease-in-out both paused;
}
.line__wrap span:nth-of-type(2){ 
  width: 2px; height: 0%; top: 0; right: 0;
  animation: lineHeight .25s .25s ease-in-out both paused;
}
.line__wrap span:nth-of-type(3){ 
  width: 0%; height: 2px; bottom: 0; right: 0; 
  animation: lineWidth .25s .5s ease-in-out both paused;
}
.line__wrap span:nth-of-type(4){ 
  width: 2px; height: 0%; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  animation: lineHeight .25s .75s ease-in-out both paused;
}

@-webkit-keyframes lineWidth { to { width: 100%; } }
   @-moz-keyframes lineWidth { to { width: 100%; } }
     @-o-keyframes lineWidth { to { width: 100%; } }   
        @keyframes lineWidth { to { width: 100%; } }
@-webkit-keyframes lineHeight { to { height: 100%; } }
   @-moz-keyframes lineHeight { to { height: 100%; } }
     @-o-keyframes lineHeight { to { height: 100%; } }   
        @keyframes lineHeight { to { height: 100%; } }

.btn__submit:hover .line__wrap span {
    -webkit-animation-play-state: running;
         -o-animation-play-state: running;
            animation-play-state: running;
}
```

При наведении на кнопку анимируются рамки, но если курсор от кнопки отвести и обратно вернуть то анимации уже не будет, можно сделать так чтобы анимация была каждый раз при наведении??? Если можно, прошу помочь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.btn__submit {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 127px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

[type="submit"] {
    margin: 27px 0 0 0;
    font-family: "futura-demic-reg", sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 1.5px;
    text-transform: lowercase;
    display: block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 9px 0;
    max-width: 127px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #111;
    background: transparent;
    -webkit-transition: all .34s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .34s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .34s ease-in-out;
}

.line__wrap span {
  display: block;
  background: #ffb400;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.btn__submit:hover .line__wrap span:nth-of-type(1){ 
  width: 0%; height: 2px; top: 0; left: 0;  
  animation: lineWidth .25s ease-in-out both ;
}
.btn__submit:hover .line__wrap span:nth-of-type(2){ 
  width: 2px; height: 0%; top: 0; right: 0;
  animation: lineHeight .25s .25s ease-in-out both ;
}
.btn__submit:hover .line__wrap span:nth-of-type(3){ 
  width: 0%; height: 2px; bottom: 0; right: 0; 
  animation: lineWidth .25s .5s ease-in-out both ;
}
.btn__submit:hover .line__wrap span:nth-of-type(4){ 
  width: 2px; height: 0%; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  animation: lineHeight .25s .75s ease-in-out both ;
}

@-webkit-keyframes lineWidth { to { width: 100%; } }
   @-moz-keyframes lineWidth { to { width: 100%; } }
     @-o-keyframes lineWidth { to { width: 100%; } }   
        @keyframes lineWidth { to { width: 100%; } }
@-webkit-keyframes lineHeight { to { height: 100%; } }
   @-moz-keyframes lineHeight { to { height: 100%; } }
     @-o-keyframes lineHeight { to { height: 100%; } }   
        @keyframes lineHeight { to { height: 100%; } }

/* .btn__submit:hover .line__wrap span {
 -webkit-animation-play-state: running;
      -o-animation-play-state: running;
         animation-play-state: running;
} */
```

```html
<div class="btn__submit">
  <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i> Отправить</button>

  <div class="line__wrap">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Воууууу, крутяк, спасибо Вам!

Comment: @МайклМиллер, если ответ Вам помог, можно отметить его решением и поставить галочку слева от ответа

Comment: @HamSter Трудно от начинающих пользователей дождаться благодарности, хватают код и гудбай. Мне понравилось решение +

Comment: @Alexandr_T, это точно, но главное чтобы ответ помог в решении)